# Python :Appending list to list changing list

Tags: python, list

I am creating a list named 'temp' in a loop and appending it to a mother list 'trouble'. When I am appending 'temp' to 'trouble' in the second run of the loop, 'trouble' itself seems to be changing.
I have simplified the code to include only this instance for clarity.

```
award=[[['A',1],['B',1]],[['A',1],['C',1]],[['A',1],['C',1],['D',1]]]

trouble=[]
print '\n'
for n in range(len(award)-1):
    temp=[]
    for i in range(len(award[n])):
            temp.append(award[n][i])
    for i in range(len(award[n+1])):
            for k in range(len(temp)):
            if(temp[k][0]==award[n+1][i][0]):
                temp[k][1]+=award[n+1][i][1]
                break
        else:
            temp.append(award[n+1][i])

    print 'temp', temp
    trouble.append(temp)
    print '\tn   =   ',n, '\n\ttrouble'
    for i in range(len(trouble)):
        print trouble[i]
    print '\n'
```

The output looks like this:

```
temp [['A', 2], ['B', 1], ['C', 1]]
    n   =    0 
    trouble
[['A', 2], ['B', 1], ['C', 1]]


temp [['A', 2], ['C', 2], ['D', 1]]
    n   =    1 
    trouble
[['A', 2], ['B', 1], ['C', 2]]
[['A', 2], ['C', 2], ['D', 1]]
```

I do not understand why ['C',1], which has not (according to me) been touched after the first instance of appending, is getting changed after the second instance of appending.

Any help will be immensely appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Anagha Madhusudanan

Comment: sorry, this is horrible code

Comment: what are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: I don't mean to be critical, but this code is nearly unreadable.  If you _absolutely_ have to have access to the numeric indices of items in a list in python, access them via `for idx, item in enumerate(lst)`.  Beyond that suggestion to help you clean this up, I have honestly no ability to decipher what you're going for.  I can't mentally map it well enough to see where you've got your appends wrong, but it isn't helping that your `award` list is deeply nested with sub-lists of differing lengths.

Comment: First code line with the definition of 'award'. This datastructure itself looks broken-by-design. What you are trying to do?

Comment: Agreed... the code ought to be bad. I've been coding in python only for about half a month... but I really need it right now. Bad code sort of works better for me than no code at all... Thanks anyways...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is all because of this:

```
temp.append(award[n+1][i])
```

The reference of award[1][1] has add into trouble twice, so any element was added, all value will be changed.
you should do a deep copy when append the list into the mother list.

```
award=[[['A',1],['B',1]],[['A',1],['C',1]],[['A',1],['C',1],['D',1]]]

trouble=[]
print '\n'
for n in range(len(award)-1):
    temp=[]
    for i in range(len(award[n])):
        tem = award[n][i][:] // deep copy
        temp.append(tem)
    for i in range(len(award[n+1])):
        for k in range(len(temp)):
            if(temp[k][0]==award[n+1][i][0]):
                temp[k][1]+=award[n+1][i][1]
                break
        else:
            tem = award[n+1][i][:] # deep copy
            temp.append(tem)

    print 'temp', temp
    trouble.append(temp)
    print '\tn   =   ',n, '\n\ttrouble'
    for i in range(len(trouble)):
        print trouble[i]
    print '\n'



# temp [['A', 2], ['B', 1], ['C', 1]]
    # n   =    0 
    # trouble
# [['A', 2], ['B', 1], ['C', 1]]


# temp [['A', 2], ['C', 2], ['D', 1]]
    # n   =    1 
    # trouble
# [['A', 2], ['B', 1], ['C', 1]]
# [['A', 2], ['C', 2], ['D', 1]]
```